# Sum values in range that meets conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have the table shown below.

It lists a number of tasks and working hours for a number of days.

The green line, starts a new day, so in this case you can see 3 days.

[image]

My question is:

**How can I sum the values of column J where the corresponding cell in the B column includes the substring ABUDHABI and put the result into the cell in row column H for the relevant day?**

The days will not have the same amount of tasks and can be found by looking for all tasks of the same date or all tasks until the next day, that meens where column A matches Arbejdsdag. I have tried to use the SUMIF formula without any luck: `=IF(AND($A25="Arbejdsdag";COUNTBLANK($J25)=0);SUMIF(J26:J$400;C26=C25);"")`

My thoughts about the formula:
I will first check if the cell in column A = "Arbejdsdag" and that the cell in column J isn't empty. If both are true, I will sum the values for the specific day. But, only the values of column J that has "ABUDHABI" in their description. It may though be a substring. So, in the case of row 25 it will sum row 26 and 28.

The problem with my formula is that it stops working on the test of one date equals another. So, I haven't completed the formula jet, as I ran into that problem.

Also not that the values of column C is:"Equal the cell ablove". Unless it is a green line. Then it is "10/02/2016" formatted as a date.

Comment: You screenshot doesn't covert the ranges which is mentioned your formula. =SUMIF(A2:A6,"ABUDHABI",B2:B6) adjust the ranges to suite your requirement.

Comment: @Sixthsense Sorry, I have fixed the formula now.

Comment: "cell in the **B** column includes the substring **ABUDHABI**" but your formula contains `$A25="Arbejdsdag"`. Please have a look on your formula in Excel again, as much as you can improve it to do what you need to do. Then post your improved formula and also please explain what is the exact problem with it (giving error message / wrong results...)

Comment: @MátéJuhász I have given it one more try now :)

Comment: *"column A = "Arbejdsdag""*, *"in the case of row 25 it will sum row 26 and 28"* you are mixing conditions for single rows (e.g. 26, 28) and days (e.g. row 25). Also it's not clear where do you want to place your results, in which column?

Comment: @MátéJuhász The result shall be placed in the main line for the day (the green line) in column H. Therefore, there will be one for each day and not one for each task. I don't know what you meen by mixing conditions. First I check if the row is a green line and if so, I shall sum all the tasks until the next day, where the task description in column B contains ABUDHABI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, some notes:

- you can't just compare cells across rows in `SUMIFS`, but compare them against current row (`C26:C$400;C25`)
- use wildcard for `ABUDHABI*`

`=IF(AND($A25="Arbejdsdag";COUNTBLANK($J25)=0);SUMIFS(J26:J$400;C26:C$400;C25;B26:B$400;"ABUDHABI*");"")`